# Bash and echo command unexpected results

Tags: json, bash, echo

I am running an echo command in bash and I am seeing some unexpected results.

When running:

```bash
echo "{
    "outputs": {
      "result": "[{\"directory\":\"mydir\",\"somekey\":\"somevalue\"}]"
    },
    "outcome": "success",
    "conclusion": "success"
  }"
```

The output is:

```
{
    outputs: {
      result: ["directory":"mydir"]
    },
    outcome: success,
    conclusion: success
  } {
    outputs: {
      result: ["somekey":"somevalue"]
    },
    outcome: success,
    conclusion: success
  }
```

I understand that the result key is not valid json but why does the output seem to iterate of the values in the result array and output the objects? What causes this in the bash or echo command side?

If I remove the double quotes on from the beginning and the end of the result array, it outputs the entire json blob as expected but curious why I get the other output when json is malformed.

Comment: Hint: Try `echo foo{bar,baz,quux}`.

Comment: Note that quotes don't nest. So for example, in `echo "{
    "outputs": ...`, the double-quote before `outputs` is a *close* quote (not part of the quoted string), and the one after `output` is the open quote of another quoted section of the string. You probably don't want most of those quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is called [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion). At its most simple, it looks like

```
$ echo {a,b}
a b
```

If the braces are embedded in a string, the entire string gets repeated:

```
$ echo prefix{a,b}suffix
prefixasuffix prefixbsuffix
```

Importantly, when the braces are quoted, the expansion doesn't happen:

```
$ echo "prefix{a,b}suffix"
prefix{a,b}suffix
```

In your case, `prefix` is

```bash
"{
    "outputs": {
      "result": "[
```

`a` is

```bash
\"directory\":\"mydir\"
```

`b` is

```bash
\"somekey\":\"somevalue\"
```

and `suffix` is

```bash
]"
    },
    "outcome": "success",
    "conclusion": "success"
  }"
```